# How to transfer Android contacts to iPhone?

Tags: contacts, ios, data-transfer

I want to move contacts from Android phone to my new iPhone. Do you know how to move Android contacts to iPhone?

Comment: A.SE mods - The answer here is a bit of software that runs on android, while there's an IOS system involved. Annoyingly, its a newer, more up to date answer than the potential dupes. I'll drop this on your lap, but I almost moved it to ask different instead

Comment: Please mention your phone model and Android version.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Android application made by Apple : [Move to iOS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios).

The applications will let you easily transfer your contact and a lot of other data (messages, photos, Google account, bookmark) from your Android phone to your iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Read this article from google support website on [How to Sync contacts with your Apple device](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2753077?hl=en),

Google recommends you to use [CardDav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CardDAV).

> To sync your Google contacts with your Apple device (iPhone, iPad,
>   iPod touch, Mac), we recommend using CardDAV, which is an Internet
>   open standard. When you sync your Google contacts using CardDAV,
>   you’ll be able to edit, add, and remove contacts from your device and
>   keep them in sync everywhere you use them.

**iOS 7+ steps:**

> 1. Open the Settings app on your device.
> 2. Select Mail, Contacts, Calendars.
> 3. Select Add Account.
> 4. Select Google.
> 5. Fill out your account information in the following fields:
>      *Name*: Enter your name
>      *User Name*: Enter your full Google Account or Google Apps email address.
>      *Password*: Your Google Account or Google Apps password. (If you’ve enabled 2 Step verification, you’ll need to generate and enter an
>      application specific password.)
>      *Description*: Enter a description of the account (e.g. Personal Contacts).
> 6. Select Next at the top of your screen.
> 7. Make sure that the "Contacts" option is turned ON. The switch should be green.
> 8. Select Save at the top of your screen.
>
> After you've completed setup, open the Contacts app on your device,
>   and syncing will automatically begin.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could try an application to transfer your contacts to PC first and then you can use iCloud or the application to put contacts into your iPhone.