# How can I transfer the numbers from my old Android phone onto my new iPhone if I lost the old Android phone?

Tags: applications, data-recovery, data-transfer, ios, verizon

I lost my old android phone. Decided to try out an iphone just to get literate. I'm wondering what the process is for transferring my contacts from my old android phone (which i don't have access to) to my new iphone.

I'm using Verizon as a provider, so might be able to leverage their cloud, though I am not sure if that's an option. I'm wondering if anyone else has done this before, and / or knows of a standard way to go about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer Android contacts to iPhone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123986/how-to-transfer-android-contacts-to-iphone)

Comment: If you lost your phone then everything that was on it is lost the only way to recover things from it would be if they were saved to the cloud so check in Google contacts if your contacts were saved there and then move them to your iPhone

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio good recommendation! unfortunately that one doesn't solve my problem, because it requires you to have possession of the old android device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this on my iphone through google.

1. I went into the Settings App of my iphone
2. Went into the Passwords & Accounts section, and hit the Add Account button which allowed me to add my google account,
3. A screen popped up which let me choose what to pull over (mail, contacts, calendars). Via this method, i was able to update my phone with all my old contacts.

I was able to do this because android had either auto-backed up my contacts through one of my google apps, or because i had initiated that process manually in the past (don't remember which).

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

If you were syncing contacts with your Google account you can login to your google.com account. In the top-right corner, just left of your photo there is a menu, where you choose "Contacts". You can browse your contacts there and even export them in CSV format.

You can than import these contacts to your Apple Accounts and voilà, sync iPhone with the account.

Please note that CSV import in Apple Account is limited to few contacts at a time, so without programming the procedure is practical only for relatively small number of contacts.

I wonder if there is an iPhone app that would sync directly with Google Account - good candidates are Outlook Client and some other e-mail clients that can use gmail. If you find something like that please post another answer to help others.